# Finding length of the longest sequence of identical consecutive characters using pointers

Tags: c++, c++11

The below code is not working.  If I enter the input as `abcaad` then it's saying that file has stopped working..Windows checking for solution.  If I include `int i=0` after declaration of character pointer it's working. Can anyone specify the reason or help me out?

> Develop a program which prompts the user to enter a string and returns
>   the length of the longest sequence of identical consecutive characters
>   within the string using pointers to data members and member function.
>   For example, in the string "aaaAAAAAjjB", the longest sequence of
>   identical consecutive characters is "AAAAA".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

fstream ob("js.txt");

int Search(char *ch)
{
  int count1=0,count2=0;
  for(int i=0;ch[i]!='\0';i++)
  {
    int j=0;
    while(ch[j]!='\0')
    {
        if(ch[i]==ch[j])
            count1++;
        j++;
    }
    if(count2<count1)
    {
        count2=count1;
    }
    count1=0;
  }
  return count2;
}

int main()
{
    char *c;
    cout<<"Enter a string: ";
    cin>>c;
    cout<<"Longest no. of identical consecutive characters: "<<Search(c)<<endl;
}
```

Comment: And what does "not working" mean? Did it format your hard drive, or did it burn down your house?

Comment: i mean i am not getting the desired output..

Comment: `char *c;` => `char c[100];`. But in C++ you should use `std::string`.

Comment: When asking questions, please avoid "does not work", but rather write "I expected it to print X, but instead it prints Y" or something similar.

Comment: "or did it burn down your house?" Damn, dude. You work on some seriously core code.

Comment: Develop a program which prompts the user to enter a string and returns the length of the longest sequence of identical consecutive characters within the string using pointers to data members and member function. For example, in the string "aaaAAAAAjjB", the longest sequence of identical consecutive characters is "AAAAA".

Comment: @jpm:  Nice quote of the requirements, but should go into your post.  What is the input that generates the issue?  What is the expected output?  What is the actual output?  Have you used the debugger?  What are the results of your debugging session?  Please edit your **post** with the answers.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews if i enter the input as abcaad then its saying that file has stopped working..windows checking for solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Search` function looks ok to me, although you could refactor to

```
int Search(const char *ch)
```

Then, you can change the type from `c` to `std::string` (which also fixes the memory bug which is causing the crash). The call site then becomes

```
int main()
{
    std::string c;
    cout<<"Enter a string: ";
    cin>>c; // Yup, the appropriate overload is implemented. Ain't C++ great?
    cout<<"Longest no. of identical consecutive characters: "<<Search(c.c_str())<<endl;
}
```

`c_str()` extracts the data buffer from the `std::string`; a `const char*` pointer.

Comment: Pleasure. Being able to `>>` to a `std::string` is one of the cutest things you discover when moving from C; The C standard library I/O functions are so deficient you end up writing your own.